# How to make "claim" environments look like "theorem" environment?

Tags: lyx, environments, theorems

I am using LyX 2.0.5 with document class `article` and 'Theorems (AMS)' in the modules. From what I understand, the `claim` environment copies its style from the `remark` environment. I'd like it to copy the style of the `theorem` environment instead. Namely, have the word `claim`F typeset in bold instead of in italics, as it is now.

Is there a way to do this in LyX?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Define a new module

There may be other (easier) ways, but you can create a new module, based on the existing one. It's not a lot of work, you just have to copy and rename some files, then do some small modifications to them:

1. Go to the [LyX system directory](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SystemDir), and from the *layouts* folder copy the two files `theorems-ams.module` and `theorems-ams.inc`, and paste them into the [LyX user directory](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/UserDir). (To find the path to these two directories, open LyX and do Help --> About LyX.)
2. Rename both files in the User directory, to for example `theorems-ams-new.module` and `theorems-ams-new.inc`. Doesn't matter what the filename is, just something other than the original.
3. Open the `theorems-ams-new.module` and make two changes:

   1. In the first line, change the name of the module, i.e.  from

      ```
      #\DeclareLyXModule{Theorems (AMS)}
      ```

      to

      ```
      #\DeclareLyXModule{Theorems (AMS) modified}
      ```
   2. Further down, change

      ```
      Input theorems-ams.inc
      ```

      to

      ```
      Input theorems-ams-new.inc
      ```

      I.e., the filename should be same as the other file you just renamed.
4. Open `theorems-ams-new.inc`, and find the definition of the Claim environment (lines 257-271, in my version). There are two changes you should make.

   1. In the second line of the definition, change the `CopyStyle` from `Remark` to `Theorem` (optionally `Definition`, see below). This defines how it is rendered in LyX.
   2. In the sixth line of the definition, change

      ```
      \theoremstyle{remark}
      ```

      to

      ```
      \theoremstyle{plain}
      ```

      This changes how it is rendered in the PDF. The `plain` style typesets the 'heading' in bold font, and the body in italics, just like theorems. If you wish to have the body of the `claim` in roman font, use `\theoremstyle{definition}` instead. In this case you would probably also like to use `CopyStyle   Definition`, as mentioned above.

Having done these modifications, you may need to reconfigure (Tools --> Reconfigure) and restart LyX. Now, instead of loading the 'Theorems (AMS)' module, load your own 'Theorems (AMS) modified'.

### Using Local layout.

If this is a modification you need for just a single document, you can use Document --> Settings --> Local layout instead. Copy the entire definition of Claim to the Local layout, and do the changes described in point 4 above.