# How to create a new type of AMS math environment e.g. Axiom instead of Theorem?

Tags: lyx

Lyx/Latex beginner here. I'm using Lyx with an AMS article document class.

How do I add a new type of math environment such as Axiom? They have Theorem, Definition, Proposition, etc. but I want axiom, and I want it to be numbered (and possibly also a non-numbered version). I'd like it to popup in the environment menu in the top left under Reasoning just like Theorem and Definition do.

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147752/axiom-1-and-1-in-lyx?rq=1) does something related but it is a bit more involved than this and I can't figure out how to isolate the simple part from the other things they are doing there.

Thanks!

Comment: It is easy enough to just add `\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}` to the preamble (Document -> Settings -> LaTeX preamble). But LyX does not seem to generate a nice interface for it. (NB: I don't use LyX as I have other requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems I was able to get this to work by adapting the other answer, though I don't really understand it. Here's what I used.

```
#\DeclareLyXModule{Other}
#DescriptionBegin
#Defines Axiomp (primed axioms)
#DescriptionEnd
#Requires: theorems-ams-extended
#Category: theorems

Format 66

Requires    amsmath

# The environments defined (regular and starred) are :
# - Axiomp

Style Axiomp
    CopyStyle             Theorem
    DependsOn               Theorem
    LatexName             axp
    LabelString           "Axiom"
    Preamble
      \usepackage{etoolbox}
      \theoremstyle{plain}
      \newtheorem{axp}{\protect\axiomname}
      \makeatletter
      \makeatother
    EndPreamble
    LangPreamble
      \providecommand{\axiomname}{_(Axiom)}
    EndLangPreamble
    BabelPreamble
      \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\axiomname}{_(Axiom)}}
    EndBabelPreamble
End
```

Comment: Could you explain how I can change this in order to add numbering as well? To fit the numbering of the other environments (such as 'Theorem')

Comment: Note that `\usepackage{etoolbox}`,`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are redundant and you don't need them in the preamble. They served a purpose in the linked solution, but not anymore.