# Adding numbering to new AMS environment in Lyx

Tags: environments, lyx, amsthm, lyx-layouts

I used the method presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642195/how-to-create-a-new-type-of-ams-math-environment-e-g-axiom-instead-of-theorem) to create a new environment ('Assumption') in Lyx.

But this environment does not come with automatic numbering which fits with the automatic numbering of different environments (Theorem, Lemma, etc.). Is there a way to add this automatic numbering?

This is the local layout I used:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Solution**

In your Lyx document you can go to `Document->Settings->Modules` and add the modules `Theorem (AMS)` and `Theorems (AMS-Extended)`. The `Theorems (AMS-Extended)` provide a layout called assumption.

If you want the theorems layouts to be numbered separately, or within chapters, add the modules `Theorem (AMS, Numbered by Type)` and `Theorems (AMS-Extended, Numbered by Type)` or `Theorem (AMS, Numbered by Type within Chapters)` and `Theorems (AMS-Extended, Numbered by Type within Chapters)` accordingly.

**Long Solution**

If for some reason you don't want to use these modules, or want the layout to be numbered differently, and there exists a layout called "Theorem" in your file add the following to your local layout:

```
Format 66


Counter assumption
    Within section
End

Style Assumption
    CopyStyle             Theorem
    LatexName             assumption
    LabelString           "Assumption \theassumption."
    Preamble
      \theoremstyle{plain}
      \newtheorem{assumption}{\protect\assumptionname}[section]
    EndPreamble
    LangPreamble
      \providecommand{\assumptionname}{_(Assumption)}
    EndLangPreamble
    BabelPreamble
      \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\assumptionname}{_(Assumption)}}
    EndBabelPreamble
    LabelCounter          assumption
    Requiers              amsthm
End
```

Notice that this way the assumption will be numbered within sections, if you want to change that to chapters for example, you need to switch "section" with "chapter" in two places, in

```
Counter assumption
    Within section
End
```

and in `\newtheorem{assumption}{\protect\assumptionname}[section]`. Otherwise, if you want it to be with no master counter, change the two places to

```
Counter assumption
End
```

and `\newtheorem{assumption}{\protect\assumptionname}`.

Lastly, if you have another layout in your file, lets say theorem, that is defined by one of th theorem module, and you want assumption to be counted with it and not separately, you don't need to declare a new counter, and change `\newtheorem{assumption}{\protect\assumptionname}`  to `\newtheorem{assumption}[thm]{\protect\assumptionname}` and `"Assumption \theassumption."` to `"Assumption \thetheorem."`.

If you don't have a layout called "Theorem" in your file, you need to put the following code in your local layout:

```
Format 66

OutlinerName thm "Definitions & Theorems"

Counter assumption
    Within section
End

Style Assumption
    Category              Reasoning
    Margin                First_Dynamic
    LatexType             Environment
    NextNoIndent          0
    ResetArgs             1
    AddToToc              thm
    IsTocCaption          1
    Argument 1
        LabelString    "Additional Theorem Text"
        Tooltip        "Additional text appended to the theorem header"
        IsTocCaption      1
    EndArgument
    LabelSep              xx
    ParIndent             MMM
    ParSkip               0.4
    ItemSep               0.2
    TopSep                0.7
    BottomSep             0.7
    ParSep                0.3
    Align                 Block
    AlignPossible         Left
    LabelType             Static
    Font
      Shape               Italic
      Size                Normal
    EndFont
    LabelFont
      Shape               Up
      Series              Bold
    EndFont
    LatexName             assumption
    LabelString           "Assumption \theassumption."
    Preamble
      \theoremstyle{plain}
      \newtheorem{assumption}{\protect\assumptionname}[section]
    EndPreamble
    LangPreamble
      \providecommand{\assumptionname}{_(Assumption)}
    EndLangPreamble
    BabelPreamble
      \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\assumptionname}{_(Assumption)}}
    EndBabelPreamble
    LabelCounter          assumption
    Requiers              amsthm
End
```

For more information i recommend reading the Customization Guide for lyx which can be found in `Help->Customization` and perhaps read the files of the theorem modules, these are just text files.

Comment: `\theoremstyle{plain}` will set the assumption text in italic, which seems a bit much.  `\theoremstyle{defnition}` would set the text upright, but otherwise should be the same.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you for the remark, i should have pointed that out. Also note that in the Theorem (AMS-Extanded) module, the Assumption layout is defined with `\theoremstyle{plain}`  but i don't think there is a convention for this.

Comment: I really don't know LyX very well, but having helped maintain `amsthm` for a couple of decades, I do know how that works.  And actually, this question has nothing to do with `amsmath`; it`s `amsthm` that is relevant.  A lot of people seem to be confused about that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Oh! i did not notice i copied the line "Require amsmath" from the linked post. Thank you!