# Edit or add enviroments in LyX

Tags: environments, lyx, lyx-layouts

I'm using LyX on Windows 10 with AMSthm module and need to make some changes to the environments.  (Including: 1. making theorem not italics, 2. adding new environments like "Challenge" to appear also on the drop down menu, etc.)

Similar questions appear to be have been asked already, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/create-new-paragraph-style-in-lyx/8787#8787), but I cannot find a useful answer.

It seems I should define my own module?  (or Layout?)

If so, where do I find pre-existing module file, and where do I place the one that I edit?

In particular I can't find anywhere the file "stdlayouts.inc" mentioned in the answer above.

Thank you.

Comment: See if this is useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129770/how-to-make-claim-environments-look-like-theorem-environment/129779#129779

Comment: Although it is dry (i.e., not fun to read), there is a lot of information we try to keep up to date in Help > Customization.

Comment: Thank you. In the end I was able to do what I want.  Except one thing, I can't make "proof" boldface, even though I edit LabelFont
  Shape               Up
  Series              Bold.  Any idea how to do this?